# How to use Grouping in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I just wish to make my question clear. This is my **database**.

```
Title      Amount       Tags
Food       5            Hotel,Friends
Food       6            Hotel
Family     8            Hotel,Mobile
Family     9            Electricity
Food       8            Party
```

I wish to generate the report like below:

**Desired Output:**

```
Percentage     Title             Amount
53%            Food              19
                  Hotel             11
                  Friends           5
                  Party             8

57%            Family            17
                 Hotel             8
                 Mobile            8
                 Electricity       9
```

I don't have enough knowledge on LINQ. So I face lot of trouble in this finding a perfect solution.

The code I use right now,

```
var ReportingData = ReportListQuery.Where(Item => Item.Category == "expense")
                                   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Title, x.TagsReport })
                                   .Select(y => new
                                         {
                                             Percentage = Math.Round((y.Sum(x => x.Amount) / MonthExpense) * 100),
                                             ExpenseTitle = y.First().Title,
                                             ExpenseCalculation = y.Sum(x => x.Amount)
                                          });
```

And here's the output for my code:

**Output:**

```
Percentage     Title      Amount  
53%            Food       19
57%            Family     17
```

Thanks in advance. Please help me. :-(

Comment: In my oppionion you should normalize your data first and avoid multiple tags per data set. It is impossible to distingish if `Food 5` for `Hotel, Friends` means 5 total, 5 per Tag or 2 for Hotel and 3 for Friends etc. This would solve a lot of problems for you

Comment: @Serv: Thanks for the comment. Can you please show me some examples?

Comment: No, because I don't know what your data means. It is up to you, how you store your data, I just gave you a recommendation whats could be wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you don't know how to get the results per tag, right?

First of all, I strongly recommend to use meaningful names in complex LINQ queries instead of x, y, etc. Also it seems to me that you group by TagsReport for which I don't see a reason. And finally, instead of y.First().Title you can just use the group key. After applying these recommendations, your simplified query looks like this:

```
var ReportingData = ReportListQuery
    .Where(Item => Item.Category == "expense")
    .GroupBy(item => item.Title)
    .Select(itemGroup => new
    {
        Percentage = Math.Round((itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount) / MonthExpense) * 100),
        ExpenseTitle = itemGroup.Key,
        ExpenseCalculation = itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount)
    });
```

Now, to add the results per tag, you could generate another property on your anonymous type containing the list of tag amounts:

```
var ReportingData = ReportListQuery
    .Where(Item => Item.Category == "expense")
    .GroupBy(item => item.Title)
    .Select(itemGroup => new
    {
        Percentage = Math.Round((itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount) / MonthExpense) * 100),
        ExpenseTitle = itemGroup.Key,
        ExpenseCalculation = itemGroup.Sum(item => item.Amount)
        TotalTagAmounts = itemGroup
            .SelectMany(item => item.Tags.Select(tag => new { Tag = tag, Amount = amount})
            .GroupBy(tagAmount => tagAmount.Tag)
            .Select(tagAmountGroup => new 
            { 
                Tag = tagAmountGroup.Key, 
                TotalAmount = tagAmountGroup.Sum(tagAmount => tagAmount.Amount)
            })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks first of all. I tried your code, it splits the string to the tags, but not grouped and the output is nearly close but not as expected. Since I can't be able to paste the code here, I pasted there in the question. Please advise.

Comment: What is the type of TagsReport? It looks like you are trying to group by a non-equatable type. Make sure that in

    ".GroupBy(tagAmount => tagAmount.Tags)"

the lambda expression results in a equatable type, for example the tag name as string (e.g. Tags.Name or Tags.ToString()). By the way, Tags should be Tag in this case.

Comment: Tags is a string like 'Home,Food'. TagsReport is the string array split by ','

Comment: Your code works like a charm but not grouping, that's a problem here. Please help me

Comment: Ok, I suspect that the grouping does not work because the tag strings differ slightly. Try to output all the tag amounts after the SelectMany. In the output, surround the tag strings with " to see if there is an additional space or something.

Comment: I still think your problem has to do with the Tag type or its content. I see no other reason why the grouping should not work.